# SQL statement to replace field value in Magento

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I need help replacing a value field in MySQL.

I used an automated script to upload Coupons into Magento but the field "`simple_action`" imported values as "`by_percent`" instead of "`cart_fixed`". Can someone show me a query to replace the value "`by_percent`" with "`cart_fixed`"?

The:

- table name is: `salesrule`
- database name is: `magento`
- field name is: `simple_action`
- existing field value is: `by_percent`
- needed field value(new value) is: `cart_fixed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a mysql query to do this:

```
 UPDATE salesrule
 SET simple_action = 'cart_fixed'
 WHERE simple_action = 'by_percent'
```